# Macro to force Excel out of edit-mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs to run for update.

If Excel is in edit, I need a macro to have Excel exit edit mode, that is, take control.

Comment: I assume you mean within an existing macro?  could you try send keys ESC?

Comment: correct. add something to force excel. 
that an idea, how would I send an esc key? any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to do this is by using the Application.OnTimer method, but it has the "edit problem" you just noted. The called function will not get executed until the user leaves the edit mode.

You may overcome this: This solution is not very efficient, but you may yield control from a macro and regain it from a timer (or any other event you choose).

The following code is from the Excel timer function help.

While the timer is counting down (or you are awaiting other event), you can continue working on your worksheet.

```
Sub a()
  Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
  If (MsgBox("Press Yes to fire update in 1000 secs", 4)) = vbYes Then
      PauseTime = 1000    ' Set duration 1000 secs or whatever.
      Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
      Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
          DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes - THIS IS THE TRICK
      Loop
      Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
      TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
      MsgBox "Paused for " & TotalTime & " seconds" 'Program your update HERE
   Else
     End
  End If
End Sub
```

You should invoke this macro beforehand, perhaps at the open workbook event.
Also, it is possible to keep the loop going, repeating the update when you want to.

You should check if this strategy does not interfere with other features used in your particular worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as Excel will not run any macros while in cell editing mode.

Comment: If you click a button to execute a macro, the macro will run and then any Worksheet_Change procedure will run, so it gives the illusion that the macro runs before Edit mode is exited. Using Application.OnTime to schedule a different macro is viable option which worked for me.