# VBA Worksheet_Change executes after macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tool where you enter parameters, run a macro, and the result cells are populated. I have a Worksheet_Change procedure to clear the result fields if the parameters are changed to prevent the situation where a user changes the parameters and *doesn't* run the macro, as this would incorrectly imply the current parameters equals the current results.
My issue is when the macro is started when a cell is in Edit mode, the macro executes *first* and then the Worksheet_Change procedure, which erases the results. You can replicate this in its most simplest form below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Worksheet_Changed trigger"
End Sub
```

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "Sub Test completed"
End Sub
```

The debug statements show that when you edit any cell, the macro runs *before* Worksheet_Change; I was expecting it the other way. Any attempt to have the code leave edit mode still executes Worksheet_Change at the end. Does anyone have any suggestions how to leave Edit mode before the macro is run?

Experimenting with `Application.EnableEvents` has not helped thus far.

EDIT - PROPOSED SOLUTION
As there is no answer to accept, this is the proposed workaround.

Use the button to schedule the actual macro, Worksheet_Change runs in between.

```
Sub Schedule()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0.5), "Module1.ActualMacro"
End Sub
Sub ActualMacro()
    Debug.Print "Actual macro running"
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570460/11683?

Comment: Apart from running a macro via a button because it forces the cell out of edit-mode, I wouldn't know how  you'd run one while in edit-mode. But it does trigger the Change event first from that testing.

Comment: Thank you. Using Application.OnTime to schedule the actual macro does work. The button click runs a scheduler to run the macro in 1 second, Excel exits Edit mode, Worksheet_Change executes and then the actual macro runs.